# Running appium with .bat file

Tags: eclipse, selenium, batch-file, appium

I need some to help me with the below. I am having error each time i run this project. It launches the cmd but fail to run the test.

```
package Automation;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class FirstAppiumTest {

    @Test
       public void startappium () throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("cmd /c start C:\\startappium.bat");
       Thread.sleep(7000L);           

        File appDir=new File("src");
        File app = new File(appDir,"app.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 100);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver (new URL ("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
```

Here are the errors below.

FAILED: startappium
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.streamW3CProtocolParameters(ProtocolHandshake.java:238)

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

I appreciate your prompt reply. Thank you

Comment: Its possible your dependancies are out of date. Try a clean then recompile.

Comment: do you mean mvn clean ?

Comment: Yes if that is your build system.

Comment: is there a reason you start appium from a .bat file? you can do Runtime.getRuntime().exec("appium")

Comment: What do i replace with ("appium") . Will it be the path to my appium.exe ? Thank you